# oData Objective-C add a JSon stream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, odata

I try to add a Json strem form my odata server.
It work fine with jQuery, but in objective-c ther is only xml returned.

I try this :

```
DataModel *proxy = [[DataModel alloc] initWithUri:@"http://www.example.com/odata/odata.svc" credential:nil];
[proxy addHeader:@"Accept" headerValue:@"application/json, text/javascript, */*; sq=0.01"];
QueryOperationResponse *response = [proxy execute:@"Example"];
NSMutableArray *array = [response getResult];
```

It doesn't work.

How can I do?

thanks
Gwennin

Answer (score 0):

xml is what odata will return.  you will need to parse the results.  Here is a link to a great tutorial for doing that.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 0):

If the returned type is a Collection<> of some sort, the OData library does the work for you and converts it to an array of the correct Entity in Objective-C.

If you return a simple type, parse the result. An example is using XPath queries (although for my service, I had to remove from the returned XML a couple of unsupported root element attributes that Odata returned).

If you chose to use Xpath,I love this code: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html